# Typescript: Help defining a type for an Array of Arrays?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a legacy variable defined quite some time ago.

```js
export const constellationNancyRomanTable = [
  [0.0000,24.0000,88.0000,'UMi'],
  [8.0000,14.5000,86.5000,'UMi'],
  [21.0000,23.0000,86.1667,'UMi'],
  [18.0000,21.0000,86.0000,'UMi'],
  ...
]
```

However, I'm very new to Typescript - so I'm half thinking of porting this variable to a new object based syntax as I understand `type` definitions for objects, but this array of arrays is alluding me. However, I was wondering how to define such a type / interface?

I'm thinking something along this line:

```
export interface ConstellationNancyRoman = Array<Array<[number, number, number, string]>>
```

Is somewhat correct?

Comment: What exactly you want? what is your expected result?

Comment: Why not [try it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQiQGdUAbMzGBIgOUyWwE8AlCAWwbgF44BBKFExMAPAKGiA2kgCu7AEZoANHFkLlquYqgrSUZAHMAugD4TAbgBQl0JFhxsRUg6flK1Og2ZtOSACqY8mTAAFwErsAUVDRI9IysHFy8kpZwcJIADAB0GbkZSgBMACw5eUoAHOWluUoA5ACqALIItUZKqelVefkAjCUArGXlAGxZgzUNza3taZIFPdX5BQDMixWjPcPDAOx1TS1tHZI9XWXzayNrkwczcAD0AFRZzw93lkZWQA)? Right now that's not even a syntactically valid `interface`, looks like you've confused it with a `type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there: you have simply nested it one `Array` to deep, since you're defining your tuples already. This should work (use `type` not `interface`):

```
export type ConstellationNancyRoman = Array<[number, number, number, string]>;
```

[See example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2BnGwA2+AhjAJZYByRmAxogEoQC21cAvHAIJRRGIA8AbUwBXJgCNgUADRxREqbPmSZcXFFKYA5gF0AfAG4AUEdCRYcGllyXreQiXKYqtBs2oAVIuPzAAXOh2BMRklNR0jCyY7HCCRnCxAAwAdIlpidIATAAsqenSABwFeWnSAOQAqgCypGU60vGxxekZAIy5AKz5BQBsyV2llTV1DQmCma0lGZkAzFOFfa09PQDs5dW19Y2Crc35E-O980ObDTpAA).

You can use bracket notation all the way, even though for some people it might not be as readable as before:

```
export type ConstellationNancyRoman = [number, number, number, string][];
```

Comment: Hi Terry, ahhh simple - thank you for helping with this!